# OpenCV function doesn't work in pytest but works normally

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a basic function that uses OpenCV to take some N number of photos with a given interval of time between them, to be run on a Raspberry Pi. Both the test and the actual function work perfectly fine when run on my mac, and the function works as intended on the Raspberry Pi. But the test does not pass. when run on the Pi. I usually receive an error stating "(assertion failed)!_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'"

How can I make this test run correctly on all devices?

Camera Control class:

```
import cv2
import threading
import os
import time

class CameraController():
    def __init__(self, id=0):
        self.id = id
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(id)

    def turn_on(self):
        if self.camera.isOpened() == False:
            self.camera.open()

    def capture_frame(self):
        retval, image = self.camera.read()
        return image
        
class ImageCamera(CameraController):
    def image_collection(self, increment, n_photos, dir):

        dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),dir)

        os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

        for i in range(n_photos):          
            file_name = os.path.join(dir_path,'minimum_payload_image_{}.png'.format(i))
            image = self.capture_frame()
            
            t = threading.Thread(target = cv2.imwrite, args=(file_name,image))
            t.start()
            time.sleep(increment)
            t.join()
```

test classes:

```
from CameraController import CameraController, ImageCamera
import numpy as np 
import os


class TestCameraController:
    def test_is_working(self):
        cam = CameraController(0)
        success = cam.camera.grab()
        assert success == True

    def test_capture_frame(self):
        cam = CameraController(0)
        image = cam.capture_frame()
        assert isinstance(image, np.ndarray)

class TestImageCamera:
    def test_take_photos(self,tmp_path):
        cam = ImageCamera(0)
        n_photos = 5
        increment = 1
        d = tmp_path / "sub"
        cam.image_collection(increment,n_photos,d)
        assert len(os.listdir(d)) == n_photos
```

I've tried changing the OpenCV API in the VideoCapture constructor. The only time I've had a successful test with this was when I ran the test by itself but I haven't been able to recreate it.